# Collection of co-finite subsets has finite intersection property

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Let $W$ be an infinite set. $X\subseteq W$ is co-finite if $W\setminus X$ is finite. Prove that the collection of co-finite subsets of $W$ has the finite intersection property (FIP).

My work:

Let $$S: = \{X\subseteq W: W\setminus X \text{ is finite}\} $$
To show that $S$ has FIP, we want to show that for all $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ where $n\in\mathbb N$, we have $\bigcap_{i=1}^n X_i \neq \varnothing$. Let's suppose the contrary, i.e. for some $n\in\Bbb N$, suppose there are elements $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ in $S$ such that $\bigcap_i X_i = \varnothing$. So, $\bigcup_i X_i^c = \bigcup_i W\setminus X_i = W$. $W$ is infinite, so $W\setminus X_i$ is infinite for at least one $1\le i\le n$ (if not, we have a contradiction). This is a contradiction, because all $W\setminus X_i$ are finite since $X_i\in S$ for $1\le i\le n$.

Does this look good? Are there any other ways of approaching this problem?

Comment: Yes, it’s correct. As Henno Brandsma points out, you don’t actually need to make it a proof by contradiction, though the argument still uses the same basic idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^\complement = \bigcup_{i=1}^n X_i^\complement$$ by de Morgan. The finite union of finite sets is finite, so $\mathcal{S}$ is closed under finite intersections and $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{S}$ because $W$ is infinite. No need for a proof by contradiction.